# JPA @ManyToOne unidirectional: How to set the FK to null and remain children entities when parent is deleted

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a simple unidirectional **@ManyToOne** JPA(Hibernate) relationship.

**Parent.java**

```
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
}
```

and
**Child.java**

```
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = true, name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;
}
```

Getters and setters are omitted for brevity. The corresponding repositories are named `ParentRepository` and `ChildRepository` and they both extend `JpaRepository` form Spring Data JPA.

Right now when `parentRepository.deleteAll()` is called it fails with foreign key constraint violation because of `Child` entities referring to these `Parent` entities (`org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint...`).

**Is it possible to configure Hibernate to set the FK to NULL and not delete the `Child` entities when the `Parent` is deleted?**

I don't want to go for a bidirectional relationship with the corresponding **@OneToMany** because I want to avoid the complexity of keeping it in sync with any add/remove/set operation. Also, it is error-prone to `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException...no Session` exceptions because of `FetchType.LAZY` on the children collection.

Currently, as a workaround I use the bidirectional relationship:

**Parent.java**

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", orphanRemoval = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Set<Child> _children;

    @PreRemove
    private void preRemove() {
        if (Objects.nonNull(_children)) {
            _children.forEach(item -> item.setParent(null));
        }
    }
```

Comment: But you need cascade as it is?

Comment: The PERSIST, MERGE and REFRESH cascadeTypes are more of a convenience. I don't need propagation of any operations on the parent. And I definitely don't want to cascade the DELETE operation from the parent to the children. But this is what happens by default if I don't use @OneToMany.